# Functional programming side effects clarification

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm currently trying to gain an understanding about side effects in general with regard to functional programming, racket to be exact. It's my understanding that it relates to changing the state of some variable, like a global one.

Here's some code that I've written;

```
; Define a variable with the value of 5
(define x 5)

; Define a function to add 1 to x
(define addX
(+ 1 x))

; Test out values
x
addX
x
```

Which outputs 5 6 5.

Shouldn't the last value be 6? Or is the fundamental principle that I'm missing, the fact that the value is stateless when using functional programming?

Comment: The comment is wrong in your code. You never define a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your code is written, you can think of `x` as a constant – ie, `addX` does not **mutate** the `x` binding.

It's like the same as (pseudocode)

```
constant X = 5

constant addX = X + 1

print(X)     ; 5
print(addX)  ; 6
print(X)     ; 5
```

Functional programming requires the **immutable** data structures. If you approach scheme/racket with notions from other (imperative style) languages, you'll struggle and the code you produce will be very bad.

Comment: Thanks a mil. With regard to the Side-Effects though and trying to tie it into the above, how would that be explained?

Comment: You want to *avoid* side effects in a functional program. Racket does have mutating functions (list [`set!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/set_.html)), but you'll want to understand their use cases before reaching for them.

Comment: We could help you more if you show us what you're trying to do. `(+ 1 x)` is pretty hard to talk without context because it could be a part of almost any program.

Comment: I'd highly recommend something like [*SICP*](https://github.com/sarabander/sicp) or [*The Little Schemer*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/little-schemer) to get a rapid familiarization with some scheme programming techniques and patterns.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your extra comment. So essentially i'm just trying to understand in code what would be a side effect in Racket.And there doesn't seem to be anyything in the Littel Schemer with regard to Side-Effects

Comment: Racket has a convention where `!` is used in a procedure name that has some kind of side effect

Answer (score 1):

`(+ 1 x)` is an expression. The result of this expression, in the case where we have already `(define x 5)`, is `6`. That value just... percolates up to whatever tried to evaluate it. Whether we ask DrRacket to evaluate it, or we assign it to something else, like `(define addX (+ 1 x))`, what is changing is the expression is becoming the value.

So, if you want to assign a value to an identifier that is already introduced, you need to tell the interpreter to do this assignment. That form is `set!`, as in,

```
(define addX #f)
addX ; => #f
(set! addX (+ 1 x))
addX ; => 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, i think i have an understanding now of what's going on. Cheers!